# phpexcel creating duplicate sheets while updating

Tags: phpexcel

I have a workbook, which contain 20 worksheets & all worksheets are updating through a php file(a cronjob/scheduler) on a daily basis.

I am facing an issue of duplicate sheets, it is updating existing worksheets but also creating copy of all 20 sheets in each execution. It is increasing file size.

My code:

```
$styleArray = array( 'borders' => array( 'outline' => array( 'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN, 'color' => array('argb' => '00000000'),),),);


$excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$excel2 = $excel2->load('mainSites.xlsx');
$row    = $excel2->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow()+1;
$excel2->setActiveSheetIndexByName('sheetname1');
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'date')
                    ->setCellValue('B1', 'value1')
                    ->setCellValue('C1', 'value2');

$excel2->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1'.':C1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($excel2);
$objWriter->save('mainSites.xlsx');
```

from `$excel2->setActiveSheetIndexByName('sheetname1');`

A loop to pass different sheet name to put data in each sheet.
Please suggest to resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: why you don't use loop for getting all active sheet of a file instead of $excel2->setActiveSheetIndexByName('sheetname1');

Comment: Hi Mobasher Fasihy,

I am looping there & by setting active sheet(by name) updating latest row. It was working fine before, but since it got row number 39/40 it is creating replica of existing worksheets in each execution. And increasing file size.